# Calculate Number of Months Iteratively In Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series, jupyter

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
    id      date        x
0   15260   2020-01-22  1
1   15260   2020-06-13  6               
2   15801   2020-12-04  5                
3   23369   2021-01-01  4
4   15260   2020-10-13  3
5   15801   2021-01-04  1
6   23369   2021-02-05  1
```

I want to add a column that represents the number of months since the first `x` for each `id`.
The finished data frame should look like:

```
    id      date        x   y
0   15260   2020-01-22  1   1
1   15260   2020-06-13  6   6              
2   15801   2020-12-04  5   1                
3   23369   2021-01-01  4   1
4   15260   2020-10-13  3   10
5   15801   2021-01-04  1   2
6   23369   2021-02-05  1   2
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the earliest date for each id and subtract that value from each date (year and month separately, then combine deltas into the number of months of difference):

```
z = df.groupby('id')['date'].transform('min')
df['y'] = (
    (df['date'].dt.year - z.dt.year)*12 +
    (df['date'].dt.month - z.dt.month)
    + 1)
df
```

Output:

```
      id       date  x   y
0  15260 2020-01-22  1   1
1  15260 2020-06-13  6   6
2  15801 2020-12-04  5   1
3  23369 2021-01-01  4   1
4  15260 2020-10-13  3  10
5  15801 2021-01-04  1   2
6  23369 2021-02-05  1   2
```